# Is there a common name for the first order IIR averaging filter?

Tags: infinite-impulse-response

Is there a term to describe this IIR averaging/smoothing filter?

$ y[n] = \alpha x[n] + (1 - \alpha) y[n - 1] $

Comment: it should be noted that $$ 0 < \alpha \le 1 $$  for the leaky integrator to appear most like an integrator, then $$ 0 < \alpha \ll 1 $$ this is the integrator to undo the differentiator of DC blocking filter. i like to represent it in terms of the single pole value which is $$p = 1-\alpha$$ so $$ y[n] \ = \ p \, y[n-1] + (1-p) x[n] $$ and the transfer function is $$ H(z) \triangleq \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{(1-p)z}{z-p} $$

Comment: also maybe related: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4699/how-does-this-equation-correspond-to-smoothing

Answer (score 5):

This is often called a [leaky integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_integrator), a special case of a first-order IIR lowpass filter. They are discussed in more detail in several previous questions:

- [Is a leaky integrator the same thing as a low pass filter?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/is-a-leaky-integrator-the-same-thing-as-a-low-pass-filter)
- [Is there a technical term for this simple method of smoothing out a signal?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35238/is-there-a-technical-term-for-this-simple-method-of-smoothing-out-a-signal/35239)
- [Designing a practical integrator](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/designing-a-practical-integrator)
- ["Low-pass filter" in non-EE, software API contexts](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/low-pass-filter-in-non-ee-software-api-contexts/1006#1006)

Answer (score 3):

It is called an exponentially weighted moving average (EWMA) filter.  Here is a previous answer where I provided a Matlab script for computing $\alpha$ for a desired cutoff frequency: [Exponential moving average cut-off frequency](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40462/exponential-moving-average-cut-off-frequency/40465#40465)

Comment: i think Andy is correct.

Comment: I'm not gone on using Moving Average for describing an Autoregressive filter, though I've certainly heard the term before.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia calls it ["basic exponential smoothing".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Basic_exponential_smoothing)

I'd call it a first order smoother or first order lowpass filter.

Some combination of those words will probably work.

Comment: sounds to me to be a Wikipedia neologism.  but i dunno.  i guess it implies a DC gain of 0 dB, which is important.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson not so sure about the "basic" but I'd seen it called exponential smoothing or an exponential filter before Wikipedia existed :)